# QT Phonon Cross Compile

Tags: c++, qt, cross-compiling, phonon

I want to cross compile QT with phonon module. I've done qt part dozens of times, but i'm struggling when it comes to the phonon. I configured my qt with -phonon -phonon-backend and -glib options, and it seemed compiled. After that, i wrote a basic qt project with phonon video player. In spite of that i can see the qt window, i got a bunch of warnings and there is no video.

```
WARNING: Phonon::createPath: Cannot connect  Phonon::MediaObject ( no objectName ) to  Phonon::AudioOutput ( no objectName ). 
WARNING: bool Phonon::FactoryPrivate::createBackend() phonon backend plugin could not be loaded 
WARNING: Phonon::createPath: Cannot connect  Phonon::MediaObject ( no objectName ) to  Phonon::VideoWidget ( no objectName ).
```

I can see glib-2.0 and gstreamer-0.10 libraries under my /usr/lib folder but i don't know what to do with them. Is there anyone can help me?

Comment: Can you check the plugins directory under qt to to see if phonon plugin exists?

Comment: Nope, there are just QT libraries. I think just configuring QT with phonon and glib is not enough, i should cross-compile gstreamer and the other libraries, right?

Comment: yes gstreamer is required for playing audio and video